# Nginx regex is not setting variables

Tags: curl, nginx

I have Nginx 1.11.0 installed and I am trying to set variables based on this regex:

```
map $args $foo {
    "~(^|(?<pre>.*?)&)(cb\=[^&]+)(?<post>.*)"        "$pre$post";
    default                                            "cat";
}
```

Furthermore, I have

```
    proxy_cache_key  "$scheme$host$uri$foo";
    add_header Cache-Buster "$foo";
```

When I start Nginx and run a curl command:

`curl -I localhost:80/?foo=test&cb=112&bar=test`

I always get cat as the response. Any idea why? I ran this through an online regex tester and it seemed to work online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close. Here is what I was looking for:

`"~(^|(?<pre>.*?)\&)((cb\=[^&]+)\&)(?<post>.*)"`

Running the curl command with single quotes around the URL would also help escape the ampersands:

`curl -I 'localhost/?foo=5&cb=234432&bar=test'`